# Find count of value A that does not have value B

Tags: mysql, sql

```
ROW - NAME -  BRAND
____________________
1   - John -  Ford
2   - John -  BMW
3   - John -  Merc
4   - Mary -  Ford
5   - Mary -  VW
6   - James - Ford
7   - James - Jeep
8   - James - Lexus
9   - Susan - Jeep
10  - Susan - Lexus
```

How do I find the values in Column A that does not have a particular value in Column B.

Column A, let's say Name, is not unique, there are multiple rows with the same value in A (as the same person can have multiple cars)

Column B, let's say Car Brand, shows the brand of car that the person has in A. There are only a total of 5 brands possible and ideally everyone should have one of the brands - Ford.

How do I find out all the unique Names for people who have other car types, but are missing the Ford? In the above example I'm looking to find Susan.

Answer (score 2):

You can use aggregation:

```
select name
from t
group by name
having sum(brand = 'Ford') = 0;
```

The `having` clause counts the number of rows that match `Ford`.  The `= 0` says there are no such rows.

Answer (score 2):

I hope you are talking about this.

```
SELECT DISTINCT name
FROM tablename
WHERE brand <> 'FORD';
```

Answer (score 1):

If you need names with all 4 other cars but with no Ford:

```
SELECT DISTINCT name FROM t
WHERE (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT car) FROM t AS t2 WHERE t2.name=t.name)=4
AND (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM t AS t2 WHERE t2.name=t.name AND t2.car="Ford")=0
```

Comment: Well, clearly not: "In the above example I'm looking to find Susan."

Comment: Then what does "all but one" mean?

Comment: Updated, thanks for the contributions, two of the options here worked. Up voted!

Answer (score 0):

There are a lot of ways, but one answer would be:

```
SELECT DISTINCT A
FROM T
WHERE A NOT IN (
    SELECT A
    FROM T
    WHERE B = 'Ford'
);
```